# Can I check if ransomware is running by using a VM

Tags: linux, ransomware, backup, vmware

I am not an expert, but as far as I understand, ransomware will encrypt files and (for an undefined period) decrypt as well, so it appears all is well. At some point in time, the decrypting ends and your files are held hostage.

A backup can help restoring the files, but my question is how to detect the files are not already encrypted before I make a backup.

So I'm wondering if I can use a virtual machine for this purpose. In other words, before I make a backup, can I view the files with a VM (running another OS like Linux) to detect if they are encrypted?

Comment: You don't make backups **after** the ransonmware hits.

Comment: Your backup strategy is beyond flawed. If this is your strategy on a live system, please change it **immediately**!

Answer (score 3):

Ransonware will only encrypt files, they don't decrypt. That task is executed by the decryptor that you will buy from the ransomware authors later. The *undefined period* is only to force you to rush the payment without having time to try other alternatives.

You don't usually detect the files being encrypted. As soon as the ransonware starts encrypting everything, you lost the game. You either have offsite backups beforehand, or your files are probably lost. Having a network drive always accessible for backups means the ransomware will encrypt the files and all backups, making the backup useless.

Assume a ransomware can hit at any time, and keep regular, tested backups all the time. Do not have the so-called **Schrödinger's Backup**: "*The backup is simultaneously valid and corrupt until you try to restore it*".

So backup always, try to restore often.

Answer (score 1):

> can I view the files with a VM (running another OS like Linux) to detect if they are encrypted?

I don't see that you get much of a benefit by transferring the files to a VM and manually viewing them - that's going to be very labour and time consuming. Meanwhile the ransomware will be munching its way through your data.

*Generally* Unix/Linux systems have a much clearer separation between executable code and data so (IMHO) there's not a huge benefit in having a dedicated VM for examining the files. There are other, better indicators of ransomware - frequent changes to files, files which have been changed will typically have their [magic bytes](https://linux.die.net/man/5/magic) encrypted - if you follow the convention of using a suffix specific to the mimetype, this should be a fairly obvious indicator.